# merge tabs in woocommerce

Tags: woocommerce-offtopic

i merged the description and the additional information tab. the additional information content is shown in the description tabs.

it works fine, but the content from additional information is shown above the description content. i cant figure out why...

```
add_filter( 'the_content', 'customizing_woocommerce_description' );
function customizing_woocommerce_description( $content ) {

    // get attributes
    global $product;
    $attributes = do_action( 'woocommerce_product_additional_information', $product );


    // Only for single product pages (woocommerce)
    if ( is_product() ) {

        // The custom content
        $custom_content = $attributes;

        // Inserting the custom content at the end
        $content .= $custom_content;
    }
    return $content;
}



// Manipulating product tabs
add_filter('woocommerce_product_tabs', 'change_product_tab', 98);
function change_product_tab($tabs){
    global $product;

    // Remove tabs
    unset($tabs['additional_information']);

    return $tabs;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> the content from additional information is shown above the description
>   content

Because the following code calls `wc_display_product_attributes()` which displays the default content for the additional information tab:

```
do_action( 'woocommerce_product_additional_information', $product );
```

To fix it, you can turn on output buffering, run the `do_action()` and then get the output using `ob_get_clean()`:

```
function customizing_woocommerce_description( $content ) {

    // get attributes
    global $product;

    // Only for single product pages (woocommerce)
    if ( is_product() ) {

        // The custom content
        ob_start();
        do_action( 'woocommerce_product_additional_information', $product );
        $custom_content = ob_get_clean();

        // Inserting the custom content at the end
        $content .= $custom_content;
    }

    return $content;
}
```